# asyncio compute heavy network call

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to do some networking that involves compute heavy calls.  For example sending a large file.  This will block if I need to send several large files in a row, and I believe it's because sending large amounts of information is IO but still compute heavy.  So if I have functions like:

```py
async def write_huge_file(really_large_file):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        await client.post(uri, data=really_large_file)

async def simple_task():
    return await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

and a command like:

```py
async def do_work():
    while True:
        await asyncio.gather(
            write_huge_file(really_large_file1),
            write_huge_file(really_large_file2),
            write_huge_file(really_large_file3),
            simple_task(),
            simple_task(),
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
```

So there's a lot of simple tasks, but the writing of huge files ends up blocking the loop.  I looked at using `run_in_executor` with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` and this prevents it from blocking the event loop. I'm not sure why, but this seems to improve performance.

```py
def write_huge_file_sync(really_large_file):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    response = loop.run_until_complete(
        write_huge_file(really_huge_file)
    )
    loop.close()
    return 

await loop.run_in_executor(pool, write_huge_file_sync, really_huge_file)
```

So there are two questions:

1. Why would a `ThreadPoolExecutor` prevent the compute from blocking the event loop?
2. Is there an idiomatic way to handle tasks that are both IO-bound and somewhat compute heavy?

Comment: Your observation of improved speed with threading suggests the possibility of some additional blocking code somewhere, in your code or somewhere in httpx. Threading will add some context switching that is absent with co-routines.

Comment: client.post() is a blocking call.  You don't explain where the function comes from, but if there is no await in front of it, it must be blocking.  Your observed behavior suggests that a sufficiently large file takes some significant time to post, so by using multiple threads you allow several post functions to proceed in parallel.  The way to handle this is with threads, exactly as you have already observed.  Occasionally someone will say that it's wrong to mix asyncio and threading, but this use case is why that's a guideline and not a truism.

Comment: i forgot to add the await.  httpx is an async library for network calls.